# Simplify $\underset{\substack{u \in M, \, v \in M^{\perp} \\ u + v \neq 0}}{\sup} \dfrac{\|\xi(u)\|}{\|u+v\|}$?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

The linear function $\xi$ is only defined on $M \neq \{0\}$, which is a closed subspace of a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$. In a perfect world I could just set $v = 0$ and simplify it to
$$\underset{\substack{u \in M, \, u \neq 0}}{\sup} \dfrac{\|\xi(u)\|}{\|u\|},$$
although I don't think it is that simple.

I am grateful for any hints, as this could complete my proof (undergrad)

Comment: "In a perfect world I could..." - A Hilbert space is about as perfect a world as it gets.  Do you know the Pythagorean theorem? ... Also, what structure does $\xi$ have? (in particular, what is $\xi(0)$?)

Comment: Somehow it was completely overlooked that $u$ and $v$ (obviously) are orthogonal. As you say, then $||u+v||^2 = ||u||^2 + ||v||^2$ follows therefor. This results in $\sup ||\xi(u)||/||u+v|| \leq \sup ||\xi(u)||/||u||$.

Comment: It is linear, so it must be $\xi(0) = 0$.

Comment: I will, thank you for your input.

Comment: Yes, however I try to see if the inequality can be made into an equality. I doubt the answer below is legible, it is even more doubtful as no calculations are presented.

Comment: The other inequality is immediate from looking at the sets over which the suprema are taken.  Written differently, you've shown $$\underset{\substack{u \in M, \, v \in M^{\perp} \\ u + v \neq 0}}{\sup} \dfrac{\|\xi(u)\|}{\|u+v\|} \leq \underset{\substack{u \in M, \, v=0 \\ u + v \neq 0}}{\sup} \dfrac{\|\xi(u)\|}{\|u+v\|}.$$  That is, it has the form $$\sup_{(u,v) \in A} f(u,v) \leq \sup_{(u,v) \in B} f(u,v)$$ where $B \subseteq A$, so we can conclude the equality since $$X \subseteq Y \implies \sup(X) \leq \sup(Y)$$

Comment: Thank you. I've learned very much from this post. I have scanned my literature and the internet and couldn't find such form, until you posted it here, and I was therefore able to finish the proof I was working on. This was the last part. Do you perhaps have any good resources that you would recommend? Sometimes I feel like the missing link of a problem is experience and broad knowledge.